# Looping in Stata through pairs of strings

Tags: loops, stata

I am trying to set a variable equal to state fips codes given its state abbreviation.  Is there a shorter way to do this other than:

replace fips = "[fips code]" if other_variable=="[state_abbrev]"

Which I currently have 50 lines of.  I would like to create a loop, but given that I have two changing values, I don't know how to avoid looping through every permutation.

Comment: Nick's solution is what I believe Stata wants you to do, and Ricardo gave an example. Avoiding looping is a good idea.

Comment: I guess the original poster was puzzled about looping through two lists simultaneously. There is a general discussion of that within http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0009 (see Section 3). The bottom line is that you need to spell out the equivalences AL <-> Alabama, etc. somehow. (A quite different comment is that the original poster assumes it is obvious that "we" are all in the United States and know about 50 states and fips codes. It is not difficult to guess his context, but this is an international forum!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of the strategy covered in the [FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/group-characteristics-for-subsets/).

1) Create a dataset containing two variables: the state name and the associated fips code. To make this slightly more flexible, I include common semi-abbreviations for the state name. In the future, you could add a third variable that includes the two-letter state abbreviation.

```
clear
input fips str20 state
1 "alabama"
2 "alaska"
4 "arizona"
5 "arkansas"
6 "california"
8 "colorado"
9 "connecticut"
10 "delaware"
11 "district of columbia"
12 "florida"
13 "georgia"
15 "hawaii"
16 "idaho"
17 "illinois"
18 "indiana"
19 "iowa"
20 "kansas"
21 "kentucky"
22 "louisiana"
23 "maine"
24 "maryland"
25 "massachusetts"
26 "michigan"
27 "minnesota"
28 "mississippi"
29 "missouri"
30 "montana"
31 "nebraska"
32 "nevada"
33 "new hampshire"
34 "new jersey"
35 "new mexico"
36 "new york"
37 "north carolina"
37 "n. carolina"
38 "north dakota"
38 "n. dakota"
39 "ohio"
40 "oklahoma"
41 "oregon"
42 "pennsylvania"
44 "rhode island"
45 "south carolina"
45 "s. carolina"
46 "south dakota"
46 "s. dakota"
47 "tennessee"
48 "texas"
49 "utah"
50 "vermont"
51 "virginia"
53 "washington"
54 "west virginia"
54 "w. virginia"
55 "wisconsin"
56 "wyoming"
72 "puerto rico"
end

save statefips, replace
```

2) Load your primary dataset that holds a variable with state names and perform a **many-to-one** merge using `statefips.dta`.

```
sysuse census, clear

// Convert the state names to lowercase to ensure
// consistency with the statefips dataset
replace state = lower(state)

merge m:1 state using statefips.dta

drop if _merge == 2
drop _merge
```

If you wanted to preserve the case of the state names in your master data set, you could simply generate a temporary variable and use that for the merge, i.e.

```
gen statelower = lower(state)
merge m:1 statelower using statefips.dta
```

Also, once you've created the `statefips.dta` data set, there's no need to recreate it every time you want to perform a merge. You could simply bundle it along with your project's files and use it when necessary. If you find you want to add two-letter state abbreviations or make some other change, then it's practically instantaneous to recreate it.

Comment: You can specify which part(s) of the merge to keep with the `keep()` option. See `h merge`.

Comment: @Fr. Right, like this: `merge m:1 state using statefips.dta, keep(3)`

Answer (score 2):

No obvious shortcut, but in Stata

```
 . search merge, faq
```

to find a relevant FAQ by Kit Baum.

Comment: I believe Stata wants the user to do it that way.